# JQuery UI Timepicker is not open when click the text field

Tags: php, jquery

I have one question regarding to JQuery UI Timepicker. I have multiple text fields.

```
<input type="text" style="width: 31px;" id="timepicker.[1]" name="mon1" readonly="true"/>
<input type="text" style="width: 31px;" id="timepicker.[2]" name="mon2" readonly="true"/>
<input type="text" style="width: 31px;" id="timepicker.[3]" name="mon3" readonly="true"/>
```

I have called the jquery function using this.

```
$('#timepicker\\.\\[1\\]').timepicker();
$('#timepicker\\.\\[2\\]').timepicker();
$('#timepicker\\.\\[3\\]').timepicker();
```

They are working. when i clicked first text field, the timepicker shows up. the same behavior goes to the second timepicker. But when i clicked third textfield, it won't show up. I have to click outside the textfield first and then click again on the third text field,after that the timepicker shows up. The same goes to the rest of text field (I have many textfields). What is the problem and may i know how to solve it?

Thanks guys,appreciate it....

Comment: Give me some time, just want to start the experiment...

Comment: still has same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("input[id^=timepicker]").timepicker();
```

Comment: Can you explain what is $("input[id^=timepicker]").timepicker(); means? sorry i am new to jquery...

Comment: that means it applies timepicker to each input type whose id starts with 'timepicker' like timepicker.[1],timepicker.[2]....

Comment: I am sorry,wrong testing previously..now i tested it,it works like a charm! may I know what is the problem? is it because of the conflict by calling .timepicker() many times?

Comment: in jquery there is a problem occurs when we are applying same functionality in similar types like inputs,texts,etc but when we work with their props like id,class then it will show exact property which we wants....glad it works...may you can accept or vote my ans also

Comment: one more thing, when the user click third text field, i will check whether the first and second text field is filled in. so there will be an if else statement. when I use "if" how to put the above solution?because I don't want that specific timepicker shows up if previous field is null...